# javascript code to read json input and map to json output

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi

I have the following script and using it in a nifi setting, but figured its best to ask the question related to javascript itself. I would like to read the json input and map it to a specific output format. The json itself could consist of different fields so it would have to read the json in a generic way and then map to the output json based on the input fields.

```
var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");
var transformed_message = {};
var error = false;
var measurement = "test_measurement";
var sep = "\n"

// Get attributes
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback(function 
   (inputStream, 
 outputStream) {
    // Read input FlowFile content
    var type = flowFile.getAttribute('type')
    var time = Number(flowFile.getAttribute('filename'))
    var meta_name = flowFile.getAttribute('meta_name')
    var remote_source_name = 
      flowFile.getAttribute('gethttp.remote.source')

    var content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
    // 
     message or content
    var message_content = {};
    try {
        message_content = JSON.parse(content);
        transformed_message.state = (((message_content || {}).state || 
          "null"));
        transformed_message.new_records = (((message_content || 
           {}).new_records || 0));
        transformed_message.updated_records = (((message_content || 
           {}).updated_records || 0));
        transformed_message.changed_records = (((message_content || 
           {}).changed_records || 0));
        transformed_message.deleted_records = (((message_content || 
           {}).deleted_records || 0));
        transformed_message.missing_records = (((message_content || 
           {}).missing_records || 0));

          line = line + ",remote_source_name="+ remote_source_name + ",meta_name="+meta_name+",message_type=" + type + " " 
                 + "new_records=" + transformed_message.new_records + ","
                 + "updated_records=" + transformed_message.updated_records + ","
                 + "changed_records=" + transformed_message.changed_records + ","
                 + "deleted_records=" + transformed_message.deleted_records + ","
                 + "missing_records=" + transformed_message.missing_records + " "
                 + time * 1000000 + sep;


        // Write output content
        if (transformed_message) {
            outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
```

so in this script it reads a json array and parses the known expected attributes or field. Is there a way in javascript to just read all the fields or json object and then create the expected json based on the number of input fields read? We could keep the type as string and the format as a json object for now and then later add code to check whether an array or object. Hope this makes sense in what I am attempting to do.

Comment: Is the end result you seek that `transformed_message` is basically `message_content` with some default values set in case of nulls?

Comment: Please provide the input and desired output examples... or input and what you want to list from it.